# enable zswap selectively per-device?

Tags: linux-kernel, swap

Is it possible to enable zswap for some swap devices but not for others? I don't see any tunables, and quick checks show that even zram swaps end up using zswap (leading to double compression). Once `/sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled` is `Y`, all swaps seem to use zswap.